# search those records which has column value contains % sign in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch all records which has one column contained % sign in mysql

we can do this using mysql using like

for ex..

```
select * from table where column like '%%';
```

it returns all records..

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape the percent:

```
select * from table where column like '%\%%';
```

will match any row containing a percent character

Answer (score 0):

% is a special character, try using escape characters to find it. Right now you're just telling mysql to look for a string using 2 wildcard characters (%) as opposed to the actual '%' character. Try using

```
select * from table where column = 'a%' ESCAPE 'a'
```

Basically telling mySQL to "Look for the string 'a%', but remove the char a in front of it.

EDIT: Another option is just using

```
select * from table where column = '\%'
```

Doing the same thing on later mySQL versions. The backslash is the "standard" escape character.

EDIT 2: Or to actually answer your question:

```
select * from table where column = '%\%%'
```

Comment: This only finds rows which are just a percent sign. The escape/backslash is unnecessary since % is not special in an = comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the literal `%` sign with a `\` e.g.

```
select * from table where column like '\%%';
```

Comment: hey ur answer is correct but i can accept only one at a time, Thanks  :)