# How to use like condition in query to fetch strings that contains % symbol

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 strings entries in my table sample and column test
1.abc
2.abc%d
3.abc%E
Now I want to write a query to fetch all the records in column test that contains abc% using like condition. The output should be abc%d and abc%E.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search those records which has column value contains % sign in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355542/search-those-records-which-has-column-value-contains-sign-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the **"_"** underscore character in SQL query?
This may help to resolve your issue.

```
    select * from myTableName where details like 'abc%_%'
or 
    select * from myTableName where details like 'abc%_'
or 
    select * from myTableName where details LIKE '%abc\%%' ESCAPE '\'
or
    select * from myTableName where details LIKE 'abc\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

All the above queries will solve your issue, use the appropriate query based on your application need and requirement.

Reference: [Use Underscore character in wild card charecter of Like query gives me all table result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588455/use-underscore-character-in-wild-card-charecter-of-like-query-gives-me-all-table)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html), you must escape instances of wildcard characters if you do not want them to behave as such.

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by
>   the escape character. If you do not specify the `ESCAPE` character, `\` is
>   assumed.
>
> - `\%` matches one `%` character.
> - `\_` matches one `_` character.